# Check for null in least function

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table as follow:

```
user_id value1 value2 value3 value4
1       2      3      4      null
2       null   5      2      null
3       null   null   100    3
...
```

Now I want to get the minimum of value1, value2, value3 and value4 and then return the user_id with the highest minimum.

I thought about using `least` and then group by descending, but how do I efficiently check for null?
The output for the table would be:

```
user_id value
3       3
1       2
2       2
```

Comment: you can use `isnull(value1,0)`

Comment: @alfasin: No, you can't. MySQL [`ISNULL`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/comparison-operators.html#function_isnull "ISNULL (MySQL)") is entirely different from [`COALESCE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce "COALESCE (MySQL)"), it accepts just 1 argument and says if it's NULL. You must be thinking of SQL Server [`ISNULL`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184325.aspx "ISNULL (Transact-SQL)"). SQL Server `ISNULL` ≈ MySQL [`IFNULL`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_ifnull "IFNULL (MySQL)")

Comment: @AndriyM good catch! Actually I'm confusing `ifnull` of MySql with `is_null` from PHP :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`~0>>1` will give you the biggest BigInt value in mysql (should be enough)

```
coalesce(
      nullif(
           least(coalesce(value1, ~0>>1), coalesce(value2, ~0>>1),
                 coalesce(value3, ~0>>1), coalesce(value4, ~0>>1)), 
      ~0>>1), 
0)
```

or you have to do combinations (I put them all, not sure it's necessary)

```
coalesce
    (least(
       coalesce(value1, value2, value3, value4), 
       coalesce(value1, value2, value4, value3),
       coalesce(value1, value3, value2, value4),
       coalesce(value1, value3, value4, value2),
       coalesce(value1, value4, value2, value3),
       coalesce(value1, value4, value3, value2),
       coalesce(value2, value1, value3, value4),
       coalesce(value2, value1, value4, value3),
       coalesce(value2, value3, value1, value4),
       coalesce(value2, value3, value4, value1),
       coalesce(value2, value4, value1, value3),
       coalesce(value2, value4, value3, value1),
       coalesce(value3, value1, value2, value4),
       coalesce(value3, value1, value4, value2),
       coalesce(value3, value2, value1, value4),
       coalesce(value3, value2, value4, value1),
       coalesce(value3, value4, value1, value2),
       coalesce(value3, value4, value2, value1),
       coalesce(value4, value1, value2, value3),
       coalesce(value4, value1, value3, value2),
       coalesce(value4, value2, value1, value3),
       coalesce(value4, value2, value3, value1),
       coalesce(value4, value3, value1, value2),
       coalesce(value4, value3, value2, value1)
)
```

, 0)

Comment: @TerryUhlang Edited : thing the last one is the most correct one.

Comment: To "transform" `9999` back to NULL, you can use `nullif(least(coalesce(value1, 9999), ...), 9999)`.

Comment: @AndriyM right. I should to this. But that solution is rather bad anyway

Comment: If you used a really large value, like 2^31-1 for instance, it might just do.

Comment: @AndriyM sure. I'm just thinking maintenance in these case : "why the hell did the guy put 99999999999999 in this query ????" (well, if code is commented, fine ;) )

Answer (score 1):

use [`COALESCE()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce)     it Return the first non-NULL argument

```
 SELECT COALESCE(LEAST(`value1`,`value2`,`value3`),0) AS min ...
```

Comment: Dn't you need to have a value for coalesce? Like: coalesce(least(...), otherValue)? Or what does it do, if no value is given? And is it possible to only output min, if min is, lets say, greater than 5?

Answer (score 1):

If you have any of the arguments to [`least()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/comparison-operators.html#function_least) being `NULL`, then the whole result will be `NULL`. In your case you can easily convert `NULL` result into zero (`0`), which seems to be the least one:

```
SELECT coalesce(least(value1, value2, value3, value4), 0)
  FROM table;
```

In case you would like to have different default for your fields, then you need to wrap them into separate [`coalesce()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce) calls:

```
SELECT coalesce(least(value1, coalesce(value2, 2), value3, value4), 0)
  FROM table;
```

I'm using `coalesce()` instead of [`isnull()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/comparison-operators.html#function_isnull) because it is more portable.